# Decode MsgPack payload with multiple item in java using msgpack-jackson

Tags: java, jackson, msgpack

I'm trying to decode message pack payload. They payload is written in go with the following code

```
var w bytes.Buffer

testBatch := []Event{
    exampleEvent,
    exampleEvent,
}

for _, e := range testBatch {
    data, err := e.MarshalMsg(nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("MarshalMsg failed: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err := w.Write(data); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Write: %v", err)
    }
}

// w.Bytes() now contain bytes that java will read.
```

If I understand correctly, the payload now contains 2 msgpack encoded stack which is appended together.

for decoding in java, I'm using the following libaray

https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java

that project contain msgpack-jackson that handle decoding message to POJO

I manage to decode the first message in java using the following code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new MessagePackFactory());
Event events1 = objectMapper.readValue(in, Event.class);

// Event events2 = objectMapper.readValue(in, Event.class); // this doesn't work
```

`events1` contain the first struct which is decoded correctly, but I did not manage to get the second struct.

un-commenting the `events1` line give the following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@2374d36a; line: -1, column: 0]
```

My objective is to get all the struct in the payload decoded correctly in java. I could find example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming your `in` variable is an InputStream:

```
InputStream in = [..]// get the input stream somehow
Event events1 = objectMapper.readValue(in, Event.class);
Event events2 = objectMapper.readValue(in, Event.class);
```

When you read bytes from an InputStream, the position of the stream moves ahead. Each `read()` reads just the next byte.

After the first `objectValue.readValue()` the stream's position is at the end of the data. That's why you get "end-of-input".

You just need to reposition the InputStream (if it is supported). (Or create a new InputStream, if that is what you want.)

For repositioning the InputStream, read about `mark` and `reset`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html